# Can I create a neo4j constraint for uniqueness within a certain originating relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, apoc

I intend to have multiple organizations existing within my database.

Within a given organization, I'd like to enforce a uniqueness constraint on a node.

For example:

- ✅ Organization 1 creates a `Thing` with `name` of `ABC` (OK)
- ✅ Organization 2 creates a `Thing` with `name` of `ABC` (OK)
- ❌ Organization 1 creates a `Thing` with `name` of `ABC`

  - (fails due to uniqueness constraint)

I'm aware that I can add a uniqueness constraint on the `name` property of the `thing` label, but it seems that this would be a global constraint across all labels. Which would be fine if my tenant strategy was multi-database, but as of now it is not.

I'm looking to do something like the following (which isn't currently possible):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT thing_name_unique_to_org FOR (o:Organization)-[r]->(t:Thing) REQUIRE t.name IS UNIQUE
```

Is there a way to create this constraint at the Neo4j level, or should I plan to enforce this in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT thing_name_unique_to_org FOR (o:Organization)-[r]->(t:Thing) REQUIRE t.name IS UNIQUE
```

But you can try a workaround like this, using `Node Key Constraints`, provided you are using `Neo4j Enterprise Edition`.

You can store the `Organization` unique identifier, in the `Thing` node, let's say `orgId`. Then you can create a constraint like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT unique_org_thing_name ON (n:Thing) ASSERT (n.orgId, n.name) IS NODE KEY
```

This will ensure that `orgId` and `name` combination is unique.

Comment: That's a fair suggestion, and I think given the reading I've done this is about as close to a correct answer as will be possible. I either have to handle it at the app level, or include the orgId as a property on the node to enforce the node key constraint.

Thanks!